# Customer Community Plus Vs Partner Community

Tags: community

Can anyone tell me what is the purpose of customer community plus and partner community ?
Difference between customer community plus and partner community?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

These two licenses are nearly identical except that in addition, Partner Communities licenses have read access to Campaigns, and full Read/Write to Leads, Opportunities, and Events.

Partner Community Licenses were created to allow collaboration with partners, to allow you to go to market together, hence the access to Leads and Opportunities. Customer Communities licenses allow you to collaborate with customers, on things like support cases and account administration. Customer Communities Plus is aimed in the middle, at more robust customer collaboration and exposure of many more Salesforce objects and the sharing model.

A full license matrix put toghether by the fine folks at TQuila can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/a/salesforce.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuSsu_7yn04IdDRxajlZM196aGM1bUx2MHlMdERraHc&usp=sharing#gid=0

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is this doc getting regularly updated in case of changes?

Answer (score 3):

The licenses serve different purpose.

- Customer Community for Customer (Person Account/Contact). Task Object
  has Read only
- Community Plus is for Customer (Person Account/Contact). Task has
  Read/Write
- Partner Community is for Partner (Business).

If you chose incorrect license you may be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

We use the Partner License for any Partner User who need access to our Deal Registration object which is custom and requires this license.

All Partner Users who do not need access to Deal Registration on the Partner community receive a Customer License due to cost.

The only issue we have had is when someone needs to have access to deal registration after they have already been using a customer license.  Then we need to disable the customer user and enable a partner one.  Development had to be done to ensure points, reputation transferred to new user.  So far this has worked well.